# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable / decorators

Tags: python, typeerror, python-decorators, nonetype

The code is as follow, accordingly with the course:

```
def new_decorator(func):

    def wrap_func():
        print("code here before executing func")
        func()
        print("func() has been executed")

    return wrap_func()

@new_decorator
def func_needs_decorator():
    print("this function is in need for a decorator")

func_needs_decorator()
```

and the result is as follow:

```
code here before executing func
this function is in need for a decorator
func() has been executed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decorators.py", line 17, in <module>
    func_needs_decorator()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

However, if I remove the last line from the code (line 17, func_needs_decorator()), there is no error message and the result is as follow:

```
code here before executing func
this function is in need for a decorator
func() has been executed
```

I would appreciate your tips why the last line is causing the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

ok, I figured it out ;)

instead of

```
 return wrap_func()
```

there should be

```
 return wrap_func
```

.....